# Php Form Difficulties

Tags: php, html, forms

Here is an html code below which i tried to edit to make Form out of it but failed, i can't send POST request From It.I added to the html code below two things
1) tag at the beggining and at the end of this html code
2)Php Part  But it still doesnt work,maybe it is problem with the way i try to Make Form out of this
html code Or Php Part ....I Dont Know. Any Ideas ??? Would Be very appreciative For any Help! 
Form Itself :

```
<form action="site.com/formhandler.php" method="POST"> 
    <div class="row">            
        <fieldset id="contactform" class="wow bounce" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="0.5s">                
            <div id="form_result"></div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                    <input name="name" type="text" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-3">
                    <input name="email" type="text" id="email" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Your email">
                </div>                
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input name="phone" type="text" id="phone" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Your Number">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">         
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                    <textarea name="message" cols="40" rows="5" id="comments" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-center">                    
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" id="submit">SUBMIT</button>    
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
</form>
```

PHP Code which i tried to connect with the Form :

```
<?php

class db {
    public function base() {
        $a = mysql_connect('', '', '');
        $b = mysql_select_db('Form', $a);
    }

}
class form {
    public function postt() {
        if ($_POST) {
            mysql_query('INSERT INTO Form SET name="' . $_POST['name'] . '",email="' . $_POST['email'] . '",phone=' . $_POST['phone'] . ',message="' . $_POST['message'] . '"');
        }
    }
}
$q1 = new db;
$q1->base();
$q2 = new form;
$q2->postt();
?>
```

Comment: you can try to edit if ($_POST) { with if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

Comment: Check the URL or page name you have used in action part of form tag.If the formhandler.php is on the same root just write action="formhandler.php"

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if it's main suspect, but `action="site.com/formhandler.php"` is the problem. `action` attribute needs path in one of two ways. With domain or without. With domain needs to start with `http://`. If there is no domain then it will append to the current url.

Examples (for let's say current url is `http://example.com/users/`):

```
action value                  what browser see
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
foo                           http://example.com/users/foo
foo.php                       http://example.com/users/foo.php
/foo.php                      http://example.com/foo.php
site.com/formhandler.php      http://example.com/users/site.com/formhandler.php
```

Maybe it will show you some of mistakes :)

In my opinion you wanted one of these:

```
<form action="http://example.com/formhandler.php" method="POST">
<form action="/formhandler.php" method="POST"> -- script is in main webroot
<form action="formhandler.php" method="POST"> -- script is only in the same dir as current page
```

Answer (score 0):

Please correct link to action (add http):

```
<form action="http://example.com/formhandler.php" method="POST">
```

Also you need to adjust php-code to avoid problems with security and database connection.